# Web vulnerabilities

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, x-frame-options

I need the help of PHP gurus.

I am having problems with my Web application vulnerability. It is made in PHP / MySQL and I still have to correct four errors:

1. X-Frame-Options header is not set
2. Cookie Does Not Contain The "secure" Attribute
3. Cookie Does Not Contain The "HTTPOnly" Attribute
4. I need to force from HTTP to HTTPS using htaccess

Please help me. I have already researched and tested several alternatives and none have worked for me.

I have in the Remote Server:

1. Linux / Apache API Version - 20051115
2. X-Frame-Options - DENY, DENY (this is rare, because also in phpinfo I get "X-Frame-Options - SAMEORIGIN", more below)

Thanks in advance. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

1.)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
```

2,3.)

http://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-apache/

4.)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mr. Nicholas. I will try right now.

Comment: Oh Mr. Nicholas! The 4th solution works in my own local sever but no in the remote one. There, the webmaster already configured the php.ini  and the SSL are in order. I really don't know why here in my laptop everything it's OK. Have you any another idea that can help? I'm sorry about muy questions, but I really have to fix this. By the way, I'm new in web vulnerabilities. Thanks again, even if you have no time to help. Greetings.

Comment: You could try that one, it depends on your server configuration. Is your .htaccess in the root of the webserver?

Comment: Thanks again Nicholas. Well, my .htaccess is on my local and I can, of course, upload it to the sever, to the root as you ask. So, I have no idea what else I can do.

Comment: I will see your advice (the link you give me). See you later and I will tell you what happend whit this. Have a nice night.

Comment: Oops! I put the policies that davidwalsh talking about and does not work. However, when I put them on "off" we can see the site content. The remote server has HTTPS. Specifically from the "RewriteEngine On" line is that the pages are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Only the pages containing input forms in which the user could enter sensitive/confidential information, are vulnerable to Cross Frame Scripting.
In order to support legacy browsers, I'd recommend the following JavaScript solution on every vulnerable page (or Master page if possible):

```js
if ( self == top ) {
  document.documentElement.style.display = 'block' ;
  document.documentElement.style.visibility = 'visible' ;
} else {
  top.location = self.location ;
}
```

```css
html{
  display : none ;
  visibility : hidden ;
}
```